# Firebase is returning 3 times the same value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some problems after the Firebase made its last update. My biggest problem at the moment is that I am unable to fix a class of application that I had done before this update.
The class below is returning 3 times the same name in my listview, and I have 3 registered users and all 3 have different names.

Note: It returns 3 times the name of the User that the application are logged.

```
package com.example.stark.chattest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.stark.chattest.model.Message;
import com.example.stark.chattest.model.User;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
    private String TAG = "Resultado: ";
    private ArrayList<String> userName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ListView usersListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatListView);
    private ListAdapter usersListViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userName);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, SignActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        ImageButton sendImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendImageButton);

        sendImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText messageEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                Message message = new Message();
                message.setMessage(String.valueOf(messageEditText.getText()));
                message.setRead(true);
                message.setTime(22221);
                message.setSendersID(firebaseUser.getUid());
                message.setReceiversID("WTImZyGv5fcOJlGWI9fi0gdrfbd2");

                myRef.child(message.getSendersID()).child("message").child(message.getReceiversID()).child("4").setValue(message);

                //Set the Reciever Message
                message.setRead(false);
                myRef.child(message.getReceiversID()).child("message").child(message.getSendersID()).child("4").setValue(message);
            }
        });

        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                userName.add(user.getName());
                usersListView.setAdapter(usersListViewAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        myRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
    }
}
```

[Here is my DB table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAGLF.png)

Note: English is not my mother language :p

@Edit
I removed everything within the onChildChanged and put all the code in onChildAdded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change a couple of things in your code, for e.g this line

```
ListView usersListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatListView);
ListAdapter usersListViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userName);
```

write this line in your `onCreate()` method, you need to initialize only once,

and regarding querying users,you should do this in your `onChildAdded()` method instead of `onChildChanged()`, and you will not have to parse through the results with a `for` loop it will be automatically added

A little code to explain what i said,

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
    userName.add(user.getName());
    usersListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

you can remove code from `onChildChanged()`, See if this helps

Comment: Can you explain more about firebase ?

Comment: @AnandSavjani yes what you would like know ? and btw docs are the best place to start with https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html is this url different from https://firebase.google.com/docs/ ?

Comment: Yes there is some difference or you can say a major one as `Firebase` have done a major change in the way they used to be functional, the link you mentioned is about the previous docs and is applicable upto `SDK 2.5.2`, though major portion of the implementation remains the same, but there are now differences in the core implementation

Comment: Thanks man, you really helped me. Now the application is really showing all users that I have on the DB. I have another problem now, he adds new message in the database, only that it does not add in the ListView. I think it was because I had declared the ArrayList as final, and the android does not allow me to declare otherwise. I added the changes in the end of my post

Comment: You can declare your arraylist globally though if that's the problem

Comment: Thanks, i did that and i still have the problem. I think is the path to the message, i put "users", but is "users/ID/message". I'm looking now the code and trying solve this problem :D

Comment: Great @stark ask if you need further help :)